# Using xarray to write NetCDF4 to GeoTIFF, get AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute '_data'

Tags: geotiff-tiff, rasterio, rioxarray

I tried to convert GPM nc4 files from NASA into GeoTIFF, but I got an error. Here's my code:

```
import xarray
import rioxarray 
import os

os.chdir(dir_path)
xds = xarray.open_dataset(
    "3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140401-S000000-E235959.04.V06B.HDF5.SUB.nc4",
)
precip = xds.precipitation.transpose('time', 'lat', 'lon')
precip.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="lon", y_dim="lat", inplace=True)
precip.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace=True)
```

[image]

```
precip.rio.to_raster("test.tif")
```

but got error:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain the error message as text. Images are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched by others.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have an outdated version of rioxarray. This fix has been released: https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/pull/652